# Displaying json response in html using js

Tags: javascript, html, json

i am doing an soap wsdl invocation application in mobilefirst.i get the response as json from the soap wsdl.The response is stored in **result** variable.i was using **result.length** but it displayed **length undefined error**.After surfing many stackoverflow i found out that json response is not array [] it is {}. i used **Object.keys()** and printed length of my json values(name,email,...so on) now i need to print all the individual values pls help how to do it

```js
{
   "Envelope":{
      "Body":{
         "processResponse":{
            "JOB":"Manager",
            "NAME":"Rahul Sashanka",
            "PHOTO":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"
              "POSITION":"Sales Support Manager",
            "SUPERVISOR_NAME":"Ashraf Tarabulsy",
            "USER_ID":"44",
            "client":"http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessUserProfile",
            "xmlns":"http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessUserProfile"
         }
      },
      "Header":{
         "FaultTo":{
            "Address":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing\/anonymous"
         },
         "MessageID":"urn:D9785BB07F9011E5BF8B25E60F40847D",
         "ReplyTo":{
            "Address":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing\/anonymous"
         }
      },
      "env":"http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/",
      "wsa":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing"
   },
   "errors":[

   ],
   "info":[

   ],
   "isSuccessful":true,
   "responseHeaders":{
      "Content-Length":"8207",
      "Content-Type":"text\/xml; charset=utf-8",
      "Date":"Sat, 31 Oct 2015 05:33:00 GMT",
      "SOAPAction":"\"\"",
      "X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID":"9e10a9dcf92c80fa:38c0ef04:150b8318e90:-8000-0000000000022100",
      "X-Powered-By":"Servlet\/2.5 JSP\/2.1"
   },
   "responseTime":163,
   "statusCode":200,
   "statusReason":"OK",
   "totalTime":216,
   "warnings":[

   ]
}
```

```js
function displayFeeds(result){
 
  
  var ul = $('#page1display');
  
     for (var i= 0; i< Object.keys(result).length; i++) {
      
       alert(Object.keys(result).length);//displays 8 as it contain 8 elements in result
         
         var li = $('<li/>').html("NAME" +(Object.keys(result[i])).NAME);
         //li.append($('<li/>').html("PERSONNAME:" +));
 
          li.append($('<hr>'));
          ul.append(li);
    }
}
```

```html
<script>
  $.getScript(path + "js/Page1.js");
</script>

<p id="currentPage"> </p>



<input type="button" id="hr" class="appButton" value="HR" onclick="funchr();" />
<ul id="page1display"> </ul>
```

Comment: can you paste your json code here?

Answer (score 1):

first of all your response got one error on line seven doesn't have comma after

```
 "PHOTO":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"
```

and this is just single response so it only printing single name seven time. you can change it according to yourself.

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      var jsonresponse = {
                           "Envelope":{
                              "Body":{
                                 "processResponse":{
                                    "JOB":"Manager",
                                    "NAME":"Rahul Sashanka",
                                    "PHOTO":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD",
                                      "POSITION":"Sales Support Manager",
                                    "SUPERVISOR_NAME":"Ashraf Tarabulsy",
                                    "USER_ID":"44",
                                    "client":"http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessUserProfile",
                                    "xmlns":"http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessUserProfile"
                                 }
                              },
                              "Header":{
                                 "FaultTo":{
                                    "Address":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing\/anonymous"
                                 },
                                 "MessageID":"urn:D9785BB07F9011E5BF8B25E60F40847D",
                                 "ReplyTo":{
                                    "Address":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing\/anonymous"
                                 }
                              },
                              "env":"http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/",
                              "wsa":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing"
                           },
                           "errors":[

                           ],
                           "info":[

                           ],
                           "isSuccessful":true,
                           "responseHeaders":{
                              "Content-Length":"8207",
                              "Content-Type":"text\/xml; charset=utf-8",
                              "Date":"Sat, 31 Oct 2015 05:33:00 GMT",
                              "SOAPAction":"\"\"",
                              "X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID":"9e10a9dcf92c80fa:38c0ef04:150b8318e90:-8000-0000000000022100",
                              "X-Powered-By":"Servlet\/2.5 JSP\/2.1"
                           },
                           "responseTime":163,
                           "statusCode":200,
                           "statusReason":"OK",
                           "totalTime":216,
                           "warnings":[

                           ]
               };

for (var i= 0; i< Object.keys(jsonresponse).length; i++) {
   console.log(jsonresponse.Envelope.Body.processResponse.NAME);
};

})
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry its not an error i have removed that as its very large binary value to paste here

Answer (score 1):

David
Try this

```
function displayFeeds(result){

     var ul = $('#page1display');

     for (var i= 0; i< Object.keys(result).length; i++) {
         // Object.keys(result) returns key names in the json

         var li = $('<li/>').html("NAME" +result[Object.keys(result)[i]]);

          li.append($('<hr>'));
          ul.append(li);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: getting NAME undefined 7 times

Comment: provide your result data

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the whole JSON using a recursive method that creates nested `<ul>` `<li>` elements that corresponds to the structure of the JSON. Here is an example :

```js
var ul, li;
function renderJSON(jsonItem, ulElement) {
    for (index in jsonItem) {
        li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = index; 
        ulElement.appendChild(li); 

        if (typeof jsonItem[index] == 'object') {
            //recursively iterate over child object
            ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ulElement.appendChild(ul);
            renderJSON(jsonItem[index], ul);
        }     
    }
}

var ulRoot = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(ulRoot);

renderJSON(json, ulRoot);
```

The above function produces markup like this :

```html
<ul>
    <li>Envelope</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Body</li>
        <ul>
            <li>processResponse</li>
            <ul>
                <li>JOB</li>
                <li>NAME</li>
                <li>PHOTO</li>
                <li>POSITION</li>
                <li>SUPERVISOR_NAME</li>
                <li>USER_ID</li>
                <li>client</li>
                <li>xmlns</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <li>Header</li>
        <ul>
            <li>FaultTo</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Address</li>
            </ul>
            <li>MessageID</li>
            <li>ReplyTo</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Address</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <li>env</li>
        <li>wsa</li>
    </ul>
    <li>errors</li>
    <ul></ul>
    <li>info</li>
    <ul></ul>
    <li>isSuccessful</li>
    <li>responseHeaders</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Content-Length</li>
        <li>Content-Type</li>
        <li>Date</li>
        <li>SOAPAction</li>
        <li>X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID</li>
        <li>X-Powered-By</li>
    </ul>
    <li>responseTime</li>
    <li>statusCode</li>
    <li>statusReason</li>
    <li>totalTime</li>
    <li>warnings</li>
    <ul></ul>
</ul>
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s2adfn3b/2/**

Comment: thank you anyway i dont want like these i want only particular name to be printed on client side

Comment: @david, OK - by "_i need to print all the individual values_" I thought you wanted to show the values too, but you only want the key names? Have updated the answer and fiddle to only show the JSON keys names.